# Oracle Managed Data Access Seems to Ignore Port When Using Alias

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess, odp.net-managed

I am getting the following error

```
ExceptionMessage: "ORA-12541: TNS: No listener"
ExceptionType: "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException"
InnerException: {Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "ORA-12541: TNS: No listener",…}
ExceptionMessage: "ORA-12541: TNS: No listener"
ExceptionType: "OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException"
InnerException: {Message: "An error has occurred.",…}
ExceptionMessage: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it {internal_ip}:1521"
ExceptionType: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
↵   at OracleInternal.Network.TcpTransportAdapter.ConnectIterate()"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: "   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
↵   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: "   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
↵   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
↵   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
↵   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
```

with the following alias in my config file. Notice that the port in the config file is 1522 but the error references port 1521.

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <dataSources>
      <dataSource alias="ConnectionOne" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST={host})(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME={service_name}))) " />
    </dataSources>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

Changing the connection string from

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionOne"
       connectionString="user id = ; password = ; data source = ConnectionOne"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

to

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionOne"
       connectionString="user id = ; password = ; data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST={host})(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME={service_name})))"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

fixes the problem.

From the Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8161)

> The following precedence order is followed to resolve the data source
> alias specified in the Data Source attribute in the connection string.
>
> 1. data source alias in the dataSources section under <oracle.manageddataaccess.client> section in the .NET config file.
> 2. data source alias in the tnsnames.ora file at the location specified by TNS_ADMIN in the .NET config file. Locations can consist
>    of either absolute or relative directory paths.
> 3. data source alias in the tnsnames.ora file present in the same directory as the .exe.

So, I don't think it is being read from another location.

Does anybody know what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I found TNS_ADMIN system variable caused all my headaches similar to yours. Added or removed depending on the situation fixes the problem.

Comment: The TNS_ADMIN  environment variable is used to specify the directory location for the tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: @Ry4n Thank you for your reply, but there is no TNS_ADMIN environment variable set on this system. Though, if it were, the documentation states the .NET config file should take precedence over the tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: @NadeemTaj thank you for the link. Do you believe there is an error in my connection string?

Comment: may be not. Let me think how can I help you. umm so lets starts from Oracle. Can you please explain your oracle environment? Client/server? standalone? version? Os? but that will become out of question.